# How can i extract the array of the objects in Swift?

Tags: swift

i have json objects like and parsed in an array

```
let objects = [Object]()
```

---

```
struct Object {
 name: String
 id: Int
}
```

Suppose like

```
let objects [Object(name:oscar, id: 11), Object(name:sanchez, id: 12),Object(name:emily, id: 15),Object(name:clarck, id: 31) ... ]
```

How can i take the string array as below also with this name which object belongs to ? ( so i can use object easily)

```
let stringPropertyArray = [oscar, sanchez,emily,clarck ... ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> how i will find the object ? if you have "emily" and i want to item.id which emily belongs to ?

Perhaps you want something like

```
if let ob = objects.first {$0.name == "emily"} {
    print(ob.id)
}
```

But if your goal is to search quickly, it would be better to have a dictionary keyed by the value you will be searching on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
let stringPropertyArray: [String] = objects.map {$0.name}
```

Comment: first part is ok thanks but how i will find the object ? if you have "emily" and i want to item.id which emily belongs to ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches you can use:

1. by looping (traditional approach)

> ```
> var listName: [String] = []
> for item in objects {
>     listName.append(item.name)
> }
> ```

2. by using higher order function

> ```
> let listName = objects.map{ $0.name }
> ```

There would be a case if your name property is optional and for some object, name property value is nil then we should use compactMap higher order function in order to avoid nil object in the list

> let listName = objects.compactMap{ $0.name }

To find any specific object we can use filter like below:

> let object = objects.filter{
> $0.name == "sanchez" }.first
>
> // OR
>
> let object = objects.first { object -> Bool in
> object.name == "emily" }